# Python - Get dictionary value if key is contained in a string

Tags: python, pandas, string

I have a string that contains (exclusively) one of several substrings. I want to check which substring is contained and get a value that associated to it. This is why I would do this operation with a dictionary.

Example:

```
string_to_check = 'TEST13-872B-A22E'
substrings = {'TEST': 0, 'WORLD': 1, 'CORONA':2}
```

In this case, 0 should be returned.

The background is that I have a pandas DataFrame (`df`) with a column `string_to_check` full of these strings. Based on which substring is contained in each row, I want to assign a value to the respective row of a new column of the dataframe.

Example result:

```
string_to_check       result

'TEST13-872B-A22E'    0
'CORONA1-241-22E'     2
'TEST32-33A-442'      0
'WORLD4-BB2-A343'     1
```

I guess I could use something along the lines of

```
def check_string(string_to_check):
    for stri, val in zip(substrings.keys, substrings.values):
        if stri in string_to_check:
            return val
```

combined with apply. But at the moment I feel to stupid to put the pieces together by myself.

**EDIT:**

Okay I think I solved this myself:

```
def check_string(string_to_check):
    for stri, val in zip(substrings.keys(), substrings.values()):
        if stri in string_to_check:
            return val

df['result'] = df['string_to_check'].apply(check_string)
```

But I am happy to see further suggestions for shorter / more readable / more pythonic ways of doing this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the first question, use a [`dict comprehension`](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0274/) to iterate over the key, value pairs obtained from [`dict.items()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects), and check if the key is `in` the dict:

```
>>> string_to_check = 'TEST13-872B-A22E'
>>> substrings = {'TEST': 0, 'WORLD': 1, 'CORONA':2}

>>> [val for key, val in substrings.items() if key in string_to_check]
 [0]
```

But for your actual problem, you can use [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) to join the [`dict.keys()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) with `|` character to [`pandas.str.Series.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) the [`dict.values()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#dictionary-view-objects) from `substrings`, then [`pandas.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html) the result to `substrings`:

```
>>> df
      string_to_check
0  'TEST13-872B-A22E'
1   'CORONA1-241-22E'
2    'TEST32-33A-442'
3   'WORLD4-BB2-A343'

>>> df.assign(result=
           df.string_to_check
             .str.extract(f"({'|'.join(substrings.keys())})", expand=False)
             .map(substrings))

      string_to_check  result
0  'TEST13-872B-A22E'       0
1   'CORONA1-241-22E'       2
2    'TEST32-33A-442'       0
3   'WORLD4-BB2-A343'       1
```

Answer (score 3):

Only few **advices**.

**Firstly**, in your code you can substitute `zip(substrings.keys(), substrings.values())` with **items** method of dict class `substrings.items()`.

**Then**, if you want you can a **lambda function** inside the `apply` method. This lambda function produces the desired output

```py
lambda x: [val for key, val in substrings.items() if key in x][0]
```

Be careful that if no substring is present in the `string_to_check` the function raise an error due to the `[0]`.

```py
df['result'] = df['string_to_check'].apply(lambda x: [val for key, val in substrings.items() if key in x][0])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for i in strings_to_check:
    to_return = []
    for j in substrings.keys():
        if j in i:
            to_return.append(substring[j])
            break
        to_return.append(-1)
            
return to_return
```

All the target strings are to be stored in `strings_to_check` and the returned value is a list of all the outputs of those strings, if no viable output is found for a string -1 is appended.